# Change entire CSS file on refresh

Tags: javascript, css

All other questions I've found relating to this are about changing specific elements, or changing the CSS file with a button, but what I'm looking to find out is:

Is there a script that will swap an entire CSS file whenever the page is refreshed?

I.e. I've got my core `style.css` and supplementary `{color}.css` files which replace certain elements in `style.css`, and I'd like those supplementary CSS files to be loaded randomly on refresh.

Sorry, I don't even know where, to begin with this. Hopefully, someone can offer some pointers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally this is just a matter of picking something at random, e.g.:

```
<head>
<!-- ... -->
<script>
var sheets = ["sheet1.css", "sheet2.css", "sheet3.css"];
var sheet = sheets[Math.floor(Math.random() * sheets.length)];
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + sheet + '">');
</script>
<noscript>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sheet1.css">
</noscript>
<!-- ... -->
```

(One of the rare cases where `document.write` isn't actually a bad solution.) Note the `noscript` fallback will always use the same stylesheet on browsers with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: Nice job including the `<noscript>` fallback!

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do to load a CSS-file with Javascript is to add a `<link>` element to the DOM/body and it will be loaded automatically.

So in your `<head>` section you could include a `<script>` tag that just randomly selects a `color.css` from an array and generate the link tag, preferably as early as possible in the file to prevent flickering.

```
<script>
  var colors = ['red.css', 'blue.css', 'green.css'];
  var colors_idx = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);

  document.write('<link href="'+colors[ colors_idx ]+'" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
</script>
```

*(PS. There are cleaner ways to inject HTML, keeping it concise to focus on the solution. Use your favorite approach, `document.write` can be a bit fickle.)*